# Blocking in JavaFX while waiting for a Swing dialog result

Tags: java, swing, javafx

**Background**

I have a *Swing* application.  I run *JavaFx* embedded inside the swing application.  I run a web browser (*webview*) inside the *JavaFx* application.  I add a handler to receive the web browser's `confirm` function. This handler is invoked in the *JavaFx* event thread.  The handler is synchronous and returns a `boolean` back to the *webview*.

**Problem**

To open a *Swing* dialog to the user, I need to run on the *Swing* event thread, but only return from the JavaFx callback after the dialog is responded to.

Here is an example of my callback

```
engine.setConfirmHandler(()->{
   // in JavaFX context
   CountdownLatch latch = new CountdownLatch(1);

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
      // in Swing context
      showModalDialog();
      latch.countDown();
   });

   // Wait for latch
   // HOW DO I BLOCK HERE AND STILL PROCESS EVENTS IN JAVAFX/SWING?
   return result;
});
```

**Question**

How can I delay returning from the callback, until the dialog closes, while not blocking UI events in either the *JavaFX* or *Swing* contexts?

Comment: I think I have an idea, but would it be possible to describe your problem is some more detail please?

Comment: You would use a SwingWorker, and respond to the call back either in its `done()` method or in a PropertyChangeListener attached to the worker, one that listens for `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE`

Comment: @Aris_Kortex Whether I call `invokeAndWait` or `invokeLater` the UI blocks and no input/output happens.

Comment: Never call `invokeAndWait`. And yes call `invokeLater` but use background threads

Comment: I'm not as familiar with JavaFX, but there too there is a mechanism for using background threads with a callback, Google that construct and use it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (in pure java/fx, otherwise I'm out ;)

Comment: You've not been able to find anything on [background threading in JavaFX](https://www.google.com/search?q=javafx+background+threading+site:stackoverflow.com) through Google?

Comment: not so. You can create your own call-back interface/method and simply call that from the background thread, on the fx event thread.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It seems you are not understanding the scope of this issue as it relates to simultaneous event pumps on JavaFX and Swing.  I am going to remove my responses to your comments, and would appreciate it if you also removed yours, in order to clear up this thread.

Comment: @kleopatra I change my snippet to pure Java.  Any ideas?

Comment: snippets are not good enough (they are lacking context) - please do as the help page suggests ..

Comment: The scope would be revealed in your [mcve]. Please show this to us.

Comment: I answered my own question, and I must say given this was my first question on SO, very disappointed in these comments and general community help.  My question was clearly stated, relevant, not a duplicate, and surely did not need any further explanation or context in order for a knowledgeable developer of JavaFX + Swing to read it and suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX has a way of blocking while still processing events.

Java 8

```
Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(key)
```

Java 9

```
Platform.enterNestedEventLoop(key)
```

Another thread can then `exitNestedEventLoop` to unblock, and as a bonus, can also return a value.

Java 8

```
Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(key, result)
```

Java 9

```
Platform.exitNestedEventLoop(key, result)
```

However, when calling `exitNestedEventLoop` from Swing, you must switch back to the JavaFX context.

So here's the working example (*Java 8*).

```
engine.setConfirmHandler(()->{
   // in JavaFX context

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
      // in Swing context
      boolean result = showModalDialog();
      Platform.runLater(()->{
          // back to JavaFX context
          Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(key, result)
      })
   });

   // Wait for result
   boolean result = Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(this)
   // still in JavaFX context
   return result;
});
```

Comment: Note those methods were moved to public API in Java 9; they are now part of the `javafx.application.Platform` class (just in case you change Java versions).